# Getting an error after successfully deleting an item from firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried to delete an item from firebase that I created. It actually deletes it from the database, but the page gives an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '-Lj884cBwoz7QsEyBxTK' of null

[image: screenshot of the error]

and this is my code

```
//retrieve data from database and store it in state

fetch(e){

const index = e.target.id;

      this.database.on('value', (e)=>{

let student = e.val()[index]
const student_name = student.full_name;
const age = student.age
const gender = student.gender
const email = student.email
const admission_year = student.admission_year
const country = student.country

          this.setState({
            student_id : index,
            current_student: student_name,
              current_student_age: age,
              current_student_gender: gender,
              current_student_admission_year: admission_year,
              current_student_email: email,
              current_student_country: country,
            })


  })
}


//remove student
removeStudent(){

  return firebase.database().ref('studentsInfo').child(this.state.student_id).remove()

  }
```

and the removeStudent function is simply linked to a button like this

```
<button onClick={this.removeIt} className='delete'>Delete Student</button>
```

The error mentions that the problem is in the fetch function.
I used the later to retrieve the student's info from the database, and it's working well.

The removeStudent function still removes the student from the database but creates an error related to the fetch function.

I hope I explained my problem well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `fetch` method reads like it was written to retrieve the data only once. But you're attaching an `on()` listener in there, which stays active after `fetch()` has completed. So when you remove a node, the `on()` callback fires again, and at that point `let student = e.val()[index]` may not be correct anymore, because `index` has a value you determined earlier.

If you only want to retrieve data once, use the `once()` method instead:

```
fetch(e){

    const index = e.target.id;

    this.database.once('value', (e)=>{
        let student = e.val()[index]
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you Frank, that helped indeed. It successfully deleted every student but it didn't delete the very last one. It deletes it from the database but not from the state.

Comment: I have a componentDidMount() that with a database.on() where it iterates through the database and creates an object of the student, then set it to the state. Thus, this.state.students is formed and hooked with the list on the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The data snapshot is empty after deleting the record. In your value change handler, `e.val()` will return `null`. The data that's been removed is no longer available.

First check if the snapshot is empty and take appropriate action:

```
this.database.on('value', (e) => {
    if (e.val() === null) {
        this.setState({
            // State after deleting the record
        });
    }

    return;
}
```